# Django model query selecting related items and excluding current object

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using Django 3.2

I have an Article model:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggitManager

class Article(models.Model):
    # fields
    tags = TaggitManager()
```

In my views, I try to select related articles (using tag similarity as the "distance metric").

This is the statement that returns related articles in my view handling logic:

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
    pk_url_kwarg = "pk"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    query_pk_and_slug = True
    

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        article_object = self.get_object()
        article_tags_array = list(set([x for x in article_object.tags.names()]))         
        related_articles = self.model.objects.filter(is_published=True, tags__name__in=article_tags_array).exclude(id=article_object.id).prefetch_related().distinct()        
   
        context["related_articles"] = related_articles

        return context
```

This statement however, FAILS to **EXCLUDE** the current object, in the returned QuerySet - despite my **EXPLICITLY** invoking `exclude()` on the returned QuerySet.

Why is this happening?

How do I fix this, so that the current object is not included in the returned set?

Comment: How did you retrieve `article_object`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem snippet fleshed out some more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with `.annotate(…)` to *count* the number of matching tags:

```
from django.db.models import Count

article_object = self.object
article_tags_array = article_object.tags.all()
related_articles = self.model.objects.exclude(pk=article_object.pk).filter(
    is_published=True,
    tags__in=article_tags_array
).annotate(
    matching_tags=Count('tags')
).order_by('-matching_tags').prefetch_related()
```

Comment: don't forget to import Count :from django.db.models import Count

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I notice that you invoked `exclude()` first - is the order of the chained method significant? (i.e. it does it matter?) - also, could you please explain why we're having to use `Count` here? I don't understand why we would need to use annotation here at all. Thanks

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: you want to determine the number of tags in common, so in order to provide the articles that have the most common tags, we determine this, and order by that number. It also prevents making a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` *without* a `GROUPBY` which results in the fact that the *same* article occurs multiple times in the queryset, so we can eliminate the `.distinct()`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the explanation. I get it now. However, I just run the query, and it still includes `article_object` in the returned queryset! :/

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: how do you *render* the items, can you please edit the question with the rendering logic?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry, my bad. I had to restart the server for the changes to take place - it seems. It all seems to be _tickety-boo_ now.